# Hadamard Form of a Circulant Matrix

Tags: matrices, circulant-matrices, hadamard-matrices

> **Definition:** Let a  field $\mathbb{F}$. Consider an $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix $\bf H$ over $\mathbb{F}$. $\bf H$ is called  *Hadamard* over $\mathbb{F}$ if and only if 
>   $$
> {\bf H}=\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> {\bf U} & {\bf V} \\
> {\bf V} & {\bf U}
> \end{array}
> \right)
> $$
>   where $\bf U$ and $\bf V$ are $2^{n-1} \times 2^{n-1}$ Hadamard matrices over $\mathbb{F}$.

Consider a circulant matrix ${\bf C}_4$ over $\mathbb{R}$ which is defined by 
$$
{\bf C}_4=
 \left(
 \begin {array}{cccc} 
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&1\\ 
1&0&0&1\\
1&1&0&0
\end {array}
\right).
$$
Let the $m$th power of ${\bf C}_4$ is denoted by ${\bf C}_4^m$ for some $m$. For instance, ${\bf C}_4^4$ and ${\bf C}_4^8$ are as follows

$$
\begin {array}{cc} 
 {\bf C}_4^4=\left( \begin {array}{cccc} 2&4&6&4\\ 4&2&4&6
\\6&4&2&4\\ 4&6&4&2\end {array}
 \right),&
 {\bf C}_4^8=\left( \begin {array}{cccc} 72&64&56&64\\ 64&72&64&
56\\ 56&64&72&64\\ 64&56&64&72
\end {array} \right).
\end {array}
$$

> *My Question:* Let $n$ is a positive integer number. How to prove 
>   ${\bf C}_4^{2^n}$,$n>1$, is  Hadamard over $\mathbb{R}$.

*My try:* I numerically checked  ${\bf C}_4^m$ in general is a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix). For instance, ${\bf C}_4^5$ and ${\bf C}_4^{10}$ are:

$$
\begin {array}{cc} 
 {\bf C}_4^5= \left( \begin {array}{cccc} 
10&6&6&10\\ 10&10&6&6
\\ 6&10&10&6\\ 6&6&10&10
\end {array} \right),
&
 {\bf C}_4^{10}=  
\left( \begin {array}{cccc}
 256&240&256&272\\ 272&256&240&256\\ 
256&272&256&240\\ 240&256&272&256\end 
{array} \right).
\end {array}
$$

The [Jordan canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of ${\bf C}_4$  is in the following form:

$$
\begin {array}{cc} 
 {\bf Q}=  \left( \begin {array}{cccc} 
1/4&1/4&1/4&1/4\\ -1/4&1/4&-1/4\,i&1/4\,i\\
1/4&1/4&-1/4&-1/4\\ -1/4&1/4&1/4\,i&-1/4\,i
\end {array} \right),
&
 {\bf J}= 
 \left( \begin {array}{cccc} 
0&0&0&0\\ 0&2&0&0\\ 0&0&-1-i&0\\ 
0&0&0&-1+i
\end {array} \right),
\end {array}
$$
where ${\bf C}_4={\bf Q}\cdot {\bf J} \cdot {\bf Q}^{-1}$  and $i=\sqrt{-1}$. 
It can be verified that ${\bf J}^{2^n}$ for $n> 2$ is:
$$
{\bf J}^{2^n}= \left( \begin {array}{cccc} 
0&0&0&0\\ 0&{2}^{2^n}&0&0\\ 0&0&{2}^{2^{n-1}}&0\\ 
0&0&0&{2}^{2^{n-1}}\end {array} \right).
$$
Now assume that $a=2^{\displaystyle{2^n-2}}$. Then we can checked that ${\bf C}_4^{2^n}$ is:
$$
{\bf C}_4^{2^n}= \left( \begin {array}{cccc}
 a+\sqrt {a}&a&a-\sqrt {a}&a\\ a&a+\sqrt {a}&a&a-\sqrt {a}\\ 
a-\sqrt {a}&a&a+\sqrt {a}&a\\ a&a-\sqrt {a}&a&a+\sqrt {a}
\end {array} \right).
$$
Is there another simple proof (especially based on the circulant matrices ) for this question?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Notice: $C_4^2$ is not hadamard

Comment: @Exodd The question is edited by your notice. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circulant matrices form an algebra, meaning that given any polynomial $p\in \mathbb C[x]$, then $p(C)$ is still circulant. Notice moreover that a circulant matric is a particular case of Toeplitz matrix.

Let us prove that $C_4^{2^n}$ is symmetric if $n>1$. You already noticed that $S = C_4^4$ is symmetric, but then $S^k$ is symmetric for every $k$, so $C_4^{2^n} = S^{2^{n-2}}$ is symmetric if $n>1$.

You can prove by yourself now that any symmetric circulant matrix is in particular Hadamard.

---

Notice : With the same proof you prove that $C_4^{n}$ is Hadamard if and only if $n$ is a multiple of 4.

Comment: I know what you mean. In fact, if $a(x)$ be the polynomial that is associated with the first row of an $n \times n$ circulant matrix $A$ then the $i$th row of $A$ is obtained by $x^i\, a(x)\mod{x^n-1}$ for $0 \leq i \leq n-1$. Thanks.